# Converting SED command to linux command

Tags: python, linux, shell, sed

I have a sed command which should be run in a python code on linux (using os.system() ) or converted to a python code. but I don't know what exactly this sed command do. It's appreciated If you give me the code or help me how to implement it using os.system in python, because I faced lots of errors when using os.system.

```
sed -n '1~4s/^@/>/p;2~4p' file1.fastq > file1.fasta
```

by the way, the input and output files should be defined dynamically in my python code:

```
seq_file1 = '6448.fastq'
input_file1 = os.path.join(sys.path[0],seq_file1)
os.system(os.path.join("sed -n '1~4s/^@/>/p;2~4p' "+ seq_file1 + ' > ' + os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(input_file1))[0]+".fasta") , shell = True)
```

Comment: Use [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) and friends, instead of `os.system`. The subprocess module was introduced to mitigate lots of problems with using `os.system`.

Comment: Why not rewrite it in native python instead of running an external program?

Comment: @9769953 The problem is that both subprocess.Popen and os.system can't recognize the concatenating of the string (sed command) and variable together! can you handle?

Comment: @Shawn I'm not familiar with the sed command, so I don't know what does it do to rewrite it in native python! :(

Comment: The `sed` explicitly suppresses all output (the  `-n`), then explicitly prints every 4th line, starting from the first, replacing the `@` at the beginning of the line with a `>`. Then it prints every 4th line, beginning from the 2nd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What does exactly this sed command do?

This `sed` command is running two different operations at once in this file.

`-n`: Suppress the output of whole file. Print only lines where the instruction `p` is applied to.

`1~4`: apply the next instruction in every 4 lines starting in the line #1.

`s/^@/>/p`: replace every leading `@` by a `>` and print the result.
Because of the above instruction, this one is applied in every 4 lines starting in the line #1.

`;` operation separator.

`2~4`: apply the next instruction every 4 lines starting in the line #2.

`p`: print a line.

What this means: "Replace leading `@` by a `>` in every 4 lines starting at #1 and print every 4 lines starting at #2"

### Example:

Content of `file1.fastq`:

```
@ line 1
@ line 2
@ line 3
@ line 4
@ line 5
@ line 6
@ line 7
@ line 8
@ line 9
@ line 10
@ line 11
@ line 12
```

Run `sed -n '1~4s/^@/>/p;2~4p' file1.fastq > file1.fasta`

Content of `file1.fasta`

```
> line 1
@ line 2
> line 5
@ line 6
> line 9
@ line 10
```

A good reference is: http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html

### How to do the same in Python?

The below code snippet aims to be didactic, so I avoided using many Python language resources, which can be applied in order to refine the algorithm.

I tested it a few times and it worked for me.

```py
# import Regular Expressions module
import re

output = []

# Open the input file in read mode
with open('file1.fastq', 'r') as file_in:
    replace_step = 1 # replacement starts in line #1
    print_step = 0   # print function starts in line #2 so it bypass one step
    for i, line in enumerate(file_in):
        if replace_step == 1:
            output.append(re.sub('^@', '>', line))                        
        if replace_step >= 4:
            replace_step = 1
        else:
            replace_step += 1            

        if print_step == 1:
            output.append(line)
        if print_step >= 4:
            print_step = 1
        else:   
            print_step +=1

    print("".join(output))
    

# Open the output file in write mode
with open('file1.fasta', 'w') as file_out:
    file_out.write("".join(output))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed answer. Now I can write my own sed commands :)

Comment: @AminJ If you do not understand a certain `sed` command, you still can use `subprocess.run`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `subprocess.run`:

```py
import subprocess
 
seq_file_in = '6448.fastq'
seq_file_out = '6448_out.fastq'
with open(seq_file_out, 'w') as fw:
    subprocess.run(["sed", r"1~4s/^@/>/p;2~4p", seq_file_in], stdout=fw)
```

In cases like this, when the `sed` command is that short and succint, `subprocess.run` might turn out really handy.